# Why can't we get consistent fix effect estimator in this simple model?

Tags: fixed-effects-model

This might be a silly question, but consider a model
\begin{equation}
Y_{it}=\rho Y_{it-1}+\delta_i+\epsilon_{it}
\end{equation}
Assume that $Cov(\epsilon_{it},Y_{is})=0$ for all $s\leq t-1$ (sequential exogeneity). How can we show that the fix effect estimator cannot recover $\rho$ consistently?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know: Why the standard conditions for consistency are violated, or do you want a counterexample for consistency, or do you really want a proof that it always *cannot* be a consistent estimator?

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196578/difference-of-dynamic-panel-nickell-bias-and-the-incidental-parameter-probl/196674#196674